# Can location.replace randomly select two possible URLs?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a poor-mans version of multivariate testing on our website. What I want to do is use a piece of Javascript that will randomly choose between two URLS that I declare within the Javascript and use that as the source URL for the location.replace function.

I've not tried much because I am not a programmer in any sense of the word. If I have some code I can generally make my way through it, understand it and make small changes.

Here is the code that I am currently using:

location.replace("https://www.example.com/pageA.html");

What I want to happen is that when I fire the location.replace code it will will either choose

https://www.example.com/pageA.html
OR
https://www.example.com/pageB.html

I think I have to put all this in an array?

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an array based version.

You can have multiple amounts of URLs in the array and it will choose from them.

```
let urls = [
    'https://www.example.com/pageA.html', 
    'https://www.example.com/pageB.html'
  ];

location.replace(Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length - 1));
```

Comment: Weirdly this version does not work for me. The version below yes. This seems to return a URL with value 0 or -1 rather than redirecting to the URLS you cite in your example

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to randomly choose between two options, you could do something like this:

```
let rand = Math.floor(Math.random * 2)

if(rand){
    location.replace("https://www.example.com/pageA.html");
}else{
    location.replace("https://www.example.com/pageB.html");
}
```

`Math.random` will return a random float between 0 and 1, so multiplying by 2 and rounding down will give either 0 or 1.

0 will evaluate to `false` and 1 to `true`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this code, this is an interesting approach and I will make a note of it.